# Laravel: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, test

Estoy modificando los códigos una y otra vez y siempre me sale este error. Yo diría que como lo tengo ya está bien, pero no sé.

Aquí os comparto mis códigos para que los podáis ver:

CommentTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Attachment;

class CommentTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testUser() {
        $role = Role::create([
            'name' => 'Testing 1',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'roles_id' => $role->id,
            'first_name' => 'Juan',
            'last_name' => 'Perez',
            'email' => 'first_name'.'.'.'last_name'.'@campusaula.com',
            'password' => '12345678',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $post = Post::create([
            'users_id' => $user->id,
            'title' => 'Post 4',
            'text' => 'Testing Post 4',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $comment = Comment::create([
            'users_id' => $user->id,
            'posts_id' => $post->id,
            'text' => 'Testing Comentario 4',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $this->assertEquals($comment->user->id, $user->id);

        $comment->delete();
        $post->delete();
        $user->delete();
        $role->delete();
    }

    public function testPost() {
        $role = Role::create([
            'name' => 'Testing 2',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'roles_id' => $role->id,
            'first_name' => 'Juan',
            'last_name' => 'Garcia',
            'email' => 'first_name'.'.'.'last_name'.'@campusaula.com',
            'password' => '87654321',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $post = Post::create([
            'users_id' => $user->id,
            'title' => 'Post 5',
            'text' => 'Testing Post 5',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $comment = Comment::create([
            'users_id' => $user->id,
            'posts_id' => $post->id,
            'text' => 'Testing Comentario 5',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now()
        ]);

        $this->assertEquals($comment->post->id, $post->id);

        $comment->delete();
        $post->delete();
        $user->delete();
        $role->delete();
    }
}
```

create_comments_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('posts_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('posts_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

Comment.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'users_id',
        'posts_id',
        'text'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function post() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Post');
    }
}

User.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'roles_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
    }

    public function comments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
    }
}

Post.php

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'users_id',
        'title',
        'text'
    ];

    public function comments() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Comment');
    }

    public function attachments() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Attachment', 'attachmentable');
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Esta es la captura de mi error

Comment: ¿En que parte se encuentra tu error?

Comment: Muestra la consulta y el lugar donde tratas de iterar los resultados

Comment: mi error está en: $this->assertEquals($comment->user->id, $user->id); de CommentTest.php

Comment: `$this->assertEquals($comment->users_id, $user->id);`

Comment: Te recomiendo que primero hagas un assert de cada objeto para asegurarte que es del tipo esperado. Por lo que parece uno de los objetos te devuelve un null.

Comment: Es porque la llave foránea se llama `users_id` y eloquent espera que sea `user_id`. Cambia el nombre de la columna o explicítala cuando defines la relación en el modelo. Y no es solo esa, te va a dar error en todas cuando quieras usar las relaciones.